# codeigniter insert from query how to optimized

Tags: codeigniter, insert

I want to optimized my query on codeigniter.

this query works but it seems, its  take time to insert the result to my database table.

```
$this->db->select('client_id');
$this->db->from('event');       
$query = $this->db->get();  

foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
  $client_id = $row['client_id'];
  $data = array( 'event_id' => $event_id , 'client_id' => $client_id);          
  $this->db->insert('event_entry', $data);                  
}
```

I would like to know if theres a way it to optimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing `n` number of inserts, doing just a single insert should improve execution time. You can achieve this in codeigniters active record by using `insert_batch()` .

```
$this->db->select('client_id');
$this->db->from('event');       
$query = $this->db->get();  

$data = array();

foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
  $client_id = $row['client_id'];
  array_push($data, array('event_id' => $event_id , 'client_id' => $client_id));          
}

$this->db->insert_batch('event_entry', $data);
```

Produces:

```
INSERT INTO event_entry (event_id, client_id) VALUES ('event_id', 'client_id'), ('event_id', 'client_id'), ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace all of that code with:

```
$this->db->query("
INSERT INTO event_entry (event_id, client_id)
SELECT ?, client_id
FROM event
", array($event_id));
```

And you will clearly notice the difference in execution time :) Plus in my opinion, having less code to worry about.

This query can't be run from Active Records, but it should be quite self explaining. Just like a normal `SELECT`, if fetches `client_id` and the already defined value `$event_id` by each `event` row. It then takes these values, and `INSERT` them into `event_entry`.

Note that `?` and `array($event_id)` insert the value into the query **escaped** (and safe). Never insert into query as `SELECT {$event_id}, client_id` unless you know what you're doing.

Jeemusu's solution is indeed a nice way to do it through Active Records, but if it's performance you want all the way, one query is faster than two in this case.

Comment: This is awesome, I had no idea you could build and SQL statement like this :/

Comment: It's all about taking your skills to the next level. This query can "copy" 20 000 rows in an instant, whilst the accepted solution could take some seconds.

Comment: This is definitely the answer, no denying that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use insert_batch command to insert data to database . Produce your data array with foreach loop and then use insert_batch database.http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

please let me know if you need any help